# LINQ - Querying multiple properties for potential match

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following, which queries properties on my collection to find any potential matches contained within a query passed to the method, the query MAY contain spaces:

```
var query = request.Query.ToLower().Trim();
if (query.Contains(" "))
{
    var queryArr = query.Split(' ');
    customers = queryArr.Aggregate(customers, FindCustomers);
}
else
{
    customers = FindCustomers(customers, query);
}
```

FindCustomers looks like this:

```
private static IQueryable<Customer> FindCustomers(
                            IQueryable<Customer> customers, string query)
{
    return customers.Where(
        x =>
            x.ACCOUNTNUM.ToLower().StartsWith(query) ||
            x.NAME.ToLower().Contains(query) ||
            x.ZIPCODE.ToLower().Contains(query) ||
            x.CITY.ToLower().Contains(query));
}
```

The problem with this is that when searching with spaces (for example: `CUS0001 London TestAccount`), it seems to lag a bit so was wondering if this was the most efficient way to query multiple properties in an object with multiple words

### Edit

The database is accessed prior to this, I am using EF:

```
var customers = DbEntities.Customers.OrderBy(x => x.ACCOUNTNUM).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: if you search with spaces it return correct result or only for last parameter?

Comment: It does return the correct results as it is, as I said it just seems to lag a bit when searching with spaces

Comment: Is it just Linq to Objects or is a database accessed in the background?

Comment: The database is accessed prior to this.. I'm using EF

Comment: Do you want to query the database directly, or load all the objects in memory before apply a filter to them?

Comment: Whichever would be the most efficient, I assume that would be querying the database directly?

Comment: It depends, doing this in memory can allow you to cache some data for faster access, but only if the table has no too many element. But for 99% of the case, the direct database query will be the better choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to know where is the problem is to look at the generated query.
The thing is you will have something with a lot of wheres and ors:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE LOWER(ACCOUNTNUM) LIKE "query%"
OR LOWER(NAME) LIKE "%query%"
OR ...
OR LOWER(ACCOUNTNUM) LIKE "query2%"
OR LOWER(NAME) LIKE "%query2%"
...
```

And it will be slow, because text searching is slow.

One way to optimize is to use uppercase instead of lowercase, as most DBMS are optimize for uppercase comparaison:

```
var query = request.Query.ToUpper().Trim();

return customers.Where(
    x =>
        x.ACCOUNTNUM.ToUpper().StartsWith(query) ||
        x.NAME.ToUpper().Contains(query) ||
        x.ZIPCODE.ToUpper().Contains(query) ||
        x.CITY.ToUpper().Contains(query));
```